# jQuery drop down list, on change do

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist with two values: Sponsor and Social_Worker. All I want to do is that when one of them is selected it shows one div and hides another, and vice versa if the other is selected. I managed to do this with buttons, but can't find the proper command to do it with a dropdownlist, the only information I am finding is getting the selected value.

Buttons jquery (this is working):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var det = $("#SponsorDetails");
    var all = $("#AllDetails");
    $(all).hide();
    $(det).hide();

    $("#Social_WorkerButton").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#AllDetails").show("slow");
        $("#SocialWorkerSubmit").show("slow");
        $("#SponsorDetails").hide("slow");
    });
    $("#SponsorButton").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#AllDetails").show("slow");
        $("#SponsorDetails").show("slow");
        $("#SponsorSubmit").show("slow");
    });
});
```

I tried using:

```
$("#SelectAccount").change(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#SponsorDetails").show("slow");
        $("#SponsorSubmit").show("slow");
    });
```

HTML of DropDownList:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="SelectAccount" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>Sponsor</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Social_Worker">Social Worker</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Just to see if any change to the dropdownlist does anything, but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Would you mind including the HTML you're trying to manipulate too? :)

Comment: It would be useful to see the HTML for the elements in question.  Specifically the dropdown list.

Comment: Included the dropdown list html, the elements being hidden/shown are just two normal divs, and since the buttons using jquery are working they seem to be ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using preventDefault() on a dropdown list? It's not going to do anything anyway, and might even be suppressing the info you're looking for.

Try

```
$("#SelectAccount").change(function() {
  //hide social worker and sponsor stuff
  val = $(this).val();
  if (val == 'Social_Worker') {
    //show social worker stuff
  } else {
    //show sponsor stuff
  }
 });
```

By the way, depending on how your html is set up, hiding #Alldetails and then showing something inside it won't work, since the parent might be hidden.

Edited for syntax.

Comment: I think this is a step in the right direction, but it's still not doing anything. I tried changing the val to

var value = $("#SelectAccount option:selected").val(); 

but still doesn't work.

Comment: Check this fiddle out- http://jsfiddle.net/e8PyH/1/ It's essentially the same thing. Note that I had accidentally left out some of the syntax in the answer above.

If that doesn't work, there might be something up with your generated HTML.

Comment: I replaced my dropdown list with the one you supplied and it worked. Could it be because I was using an ASP dropdown list? Thanks again.

Comment: The ASP dropdown might have been rendering slightly different HTML onto the actual output. So yes, that could have been an issue. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

for ex if you have this form with simple drop down

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('select[id$=<%=DropDownList1.ClientID%>]').bind("keyup
 change", function() {
 //do every thing you want
 });
 });
</script>
```